# ESTA declined to the US

Tags: esta

I was declined an ESTA due to answering yes in have you ever been convicted. I thought it would ask when and why to explain but no its a blanket question. I was a junior aged 16 and only received a minor police caution for possession of a controlled drug, I am now 43 and never been in trouble as an adult and I am fully SC cleared for my job.... what is the best approach?... I assume going to Canada is out the question, what a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. What if I want to travel to Canada instead? I assume the eTA would be refused because the ESTA refusal? and I would need to get a visa for Canada?

Comment: eTA should be a separate issue.  If it's refused, it will be because of your caution rather than because ESTA authorization was refused.  The entire eTA process and the remedy for eTA refusal are somewhat different.  But you'll have to fly directly to Canada; because of your ESTA refusal, you'll need a visa to transit through the US.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.... So on the eTA application it asks if you if you have been refused a permit to enter a country and I say yes and in the explanation field I fully explain they will consider the application rather than point blank refuse because I have been refused an ESTA?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  The approval will probably take a few days as it will need to be reviewed by a real person.  But it's been a while since I have completed an eTA application, so you might want to ask a new question here about that to see if someone who knows more about it than I do can answer.

Comment: You might want to check this with a lawyer, but in most cases a 'caution' is not considered a conviction. Did you go to court?

Comment: No it was just half hour down the police station with my dad as an adult needed to be present, it was a caution only at the age of 16 and I was told it would disappear when I turn 18 and I could be present to see it being destroyed. I am fully SC cleared for my job as well. i think I made a mistake saying yes to the question.

Comment: Check with a lawyer, but I'm pretty convinced you didn't need to answer "Yes" to "Have you been convicted". But now you are going to have problems because they will assume you are hiding something.

Comment: @Trev I'm not a lawyer but that doesn't really sound like a conviction to me. Unfortunately, it might be a mess applying for a new ESTA as they won't know what to do with it and likely based on the last refusal would refuse a new ESTA too, therefore probably have to go through a £160 visa application unless you can fly to Canada directly and avoiding US fully. However, maybe it's possible to apply for the new ESTA, I mean it's only $14 to lose - though I would like to hear what others think of it?

Comment: @Trev: I wouldn't take it as given that ESTA counts as "permit to enter a country". The ESTA small print is pretty explicit you can still be turned back and have no right to admittance to the US. (But I'm not a lawyer.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the same is true of US visas, however.  A US visa is not a permit to enter the US but a permit to travel to the US and request admission.  I'm pretty sure that Canada would consider that a US visa refusal requires an affirmative response to the eTA eligibility question, though I agree that it is possible they might not consider an ESTA refusal to require an affirmative response.  I would only say "no" if I found an unambiguous official statement to that effect, however.

Comment: Trev: "i think I made a mistake saying yes to the question": perhaps.  But you should be able to get a 10-year multiple-entry B-2 visa in fairly short order, which will effectively erase any effects of the mistake.  If you did in fact make a mistake, that is, if your history is not actually a "conviction" within the meaning of US immigration law, it may even be possible for you to reapply for ESTA, though I would not try to do that unless I were quite sure that it was okay under US law.

Answer (score 31):

ESTA materials say that if your application is unsuccessful you should apply for a US visa.  That is where you will have the opportunity to say "when and why and explain."

I suspect your chances are fairly good, but if you are not successful you will lose the $160 application fee.

Comment: Or read carefully the instructions (and contact consular office to be sure you interpret legalese correctly). I think after 25 year you should not more write convictions, but I really do not want to look all small print for this.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi under US law it is definitely likely that failing to mention this incident would be considered deception, which triggers a lifetime ban.  It's already been mentioned in the ESTA application.  The best course of action is definitely to apply for a visa and use the application to explain the circumstances, unless the applicant prefers to abandon the plans to travel to (or through) the US.

Comment: I do not recommend to lie. I just say that on a form the questions are short. In the relevant document they explain what should be considered "conviction" (remember that we are discussion with 190 and more other countries definitions). IIRC (for US), there were a cut off date (and about minors). The problem with drugs: minor and major offences seems often arbitrary, so one should read carefully. Your answer is correct, but possibly there is still a legal shortcut.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi true. It may be that Trev could have answered "no" to a question about conviction since he was only "cautioned" -- I do not remember what the US embassy says about this.  Others might want to take that into account, but for Trev it is probably too late as I would guess a subsequent ESTA application with a different answer would also be refused.

Answer (score 11):

The best approach is now to apply for a regular visa. AFAIK there you can explain a bit more about your circumstances in the visa interview.